# Sending Email Template to Lead on Creation of Event

Tags: trigger, workflow, email-template, leads

I am having a little trouble sending an email to a lead using a template  when an Event of type **visit** is created and again the day before the event. I can't use a workflow because ActivityDate is not available to be referenced. Also not sure how the lead's email will be determined when sending the email. I would like an example of workflow to do this.   Or perhaps Is there a a good way to go about this? Maybe a trigger. But the setTargetId of  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage does not seem to support event. Any suggestion on how I should approach this? Examples would be great.

Template

```
    <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Hello" recipientType="Lead" relatedToType="Event">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
      <p>This is a reminder about your visit on <strong>{!relatedTo.ActivityDate}</strong></p> 
      <p>Please use the details below as a reminder of your visit </p> 
      <p><strong>Location:</strong> {!relatedTo.Location} </p>  
     <p>Sincerely,</p>
     <p>{!relatedTo.Owner.Name} </p>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody> 
    </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTargetObjectId` to the contact and `setWhatId` to the event in the trigger.