# System.EmailException: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id : using Event in WhatID of singlemailmessage method of salesforce

Tags: apex, email-template

I am trying to send email to Contact through Apex class with SingleEmailMessage for Event assigned/updated for him, so used:

```
SetWhatID = Event.id;
```

It is failing to send email with below exception:

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id

Can anyone help to understand the cause of this Exception?
Please find detailed code below:

```
email.setTargetObjectId(loggedInContactId);
email.setWhatId(objEvent.id); // Event Id
email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
email.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.id); // template Id with merged fields of Event
email.setToAddresses(new String[] {toAddress});
//Sending confirmtation mail
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailmessage[] {email});
```

Comment: Please share the code in detail.

Comment: Your email template is of which type text/vsiualforce. If not visualforce, try making it vf template and then try removing whatid code line.

Comment: Yep!! it is visualforce template, after commenting What ID line, email is generated but blank values,

Comment: What values you have given in recipientType & relatedToType attributes in template?

Comment: recipientType = contact & relatedToType = Event

Answer (score 2):

When emails are saved as activities, a Task is created.

The `WhatId` on a Task cannot be an Event.

Even if you're using `SaveAsActivity = false`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is email.setWhatId(objEvent.id);

Can you try without there line?

Best regards.

Comment: without this line, the email template merged fields are blank... the value is not populated in merged fields when email is genarated.

Comment: yep, but in the what id can only send and id of Account, Asset, Campaign, Case, Contract, Opportunity, Order, Product, Solution, Custom

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setWhatId

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/35259/sending-email-template-to-lead-on-creation-of-event#

Comment: As per this link, we can use Event in whatID, Not sure...